# Why am I getting "Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2" when I have 1.3.6 installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've Google around and haven't found much...

I'm trying to run script/server for my Rails project, and I get

> Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2.
>   Please install RubyGems and try again:
>   http://rubygems.rubyforge.org

gem --version Shows 1.3.6. Rails and all gems were installed using sudo. I'm on Mac OSX 10.6.

Comment: Hmm, I did run sudo port install subversion-rubybindings the other night. Maybe that F*d things up. *sigh*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what does /usr/bin/env ruby -v
and /usr/bin/env gem -v show ?

You may be running two versions of ruby/gem and your rails app is accessing the wrong one

Also try checking your environment path and make sure its looking at the correct version

Comment: Ah, I had a ruby binary in /opt/local/bin. I've symlinked it with /usr/bin/ruby, and things seem to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I was having a similar problem on a Rails 2.1.2 app on Ruby 1.87.

I tried it through `bundle exec ruby script/server` though, and that at least allowed WEBrick to work for me.